# VS 2019 Archive Manager never finishes Archiving the (iOS) app bundle

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2019

I'm attempting to Archive my iOS app bundle using Visual Studio 2019 Version 16.11.1 and it never finishes.  Just sits there sliding back and forth.  Anyone know what that's about?

*** Screen Shot ****

[image]

Comment: Check VS output, check mac connection, and your solution configuration like debug / release, simulator / real device. Screenshots would be helpful.

Comment: I added a screen shot of what I see ... It just sits there, never completes.

Comment: Did you connect any iphone device to your mac? And select it at the green start button.

Comment: There was an iPhone connected to the Mac, but it wasn't selected.

Comment: Select your iphone, and make sure the name of iphone was display on the screenshot when start archiving.

Comment: Wow .... that did it.  Put that as the answer and I'll mark. it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To archive a Xamarin iOS project,

1. Check if **build** succeeded, or will be some exception logs in "Output" view
2. Check **Mac connection** is fine, which means a green monitor as below.
   [image]
3. Choose your **configuration** correctly (e.g. release for archiving)
4. Select a real device (NOT a simulator) with correct Provisioning  before starting as below.
   [image]

---

Updated as archive is available for iphone only.
Reference link in comment.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e55d3b38-4b05-4454-8d78-d29f5fe714cb/can-we-manually-install-an-xamarin-ios-app-to-a-simulator-without-deploying-via-visual-studio?forum=xamarinios

Comment: When I selected a simulator, the Archive still never completed.  I had to select a real device.  It may be different for other folks.

Comment: Right, archive a xamarin ios proj or build an IPA file is available for iphone only, check [this thread], guess for the certification or provisioning profile reason. And updated the answer.